# Employee turnover with R using multiple selected variables

Tags: r

I am having a few issues trying to calculate employee turnover rates using multiple variables.

See the sample data below.

```
As Of      Status       Gender    Type   Assignment
1/31/2015  Termination  Male      A       Fulltime
1/31/2015  Active       Female    A       Parttime
1/31/2015  Active       Male      B       Fulltime
1/31/2015  Active       Female    B       Parttime
1/31/2015  Active       Male      A       Fulltime
2/29/2015  Active       Female    A       Parttime
2/29/2015  Active       Male      B       Fulltime
2/29/2015  Active       Female    B       Parttime
2/29/2015  New Hire     Male      A       Fulltime
2/29/2015  Termination  Female    A       Parttime
3/31/2015  Active       Male      B       Fulltime
3/31/2015  Active       Female    B       Parttime
3/31/2015  Active       Male      A       Fulltime
3/31/2015  Termination  Female    A       Parttime
3/31/2015  Active       Male      B       Fulltime
```

I reshaped my data to count the number of Active and Number of Terminations per month with the code below.

```
dataSet <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header=TRUE)
dataSet$As.Of <- as.Date(dataSet$As.Of, format="%m/%d/%y")
dataSet$As.Of.Month <- format(dataSet$As.Of, "%m")

dataSetAgg <- dcast(dataSet, As.Of.Month ~ Status, fun.aggregate = length, value.var="As.Of.Month")
```

Using this I am able to transform the data set into something that looks like this.

```
As Of      Active       Terminations    New Hires
1/2015       4                1             0
2/2015       3                1             1
3/2015       4                1             0
```

And I am able to calculate the overall running turnover by doing

```
Running_terminations <- sum(dataSetAgg$Termination)/nrow(dataSetAgg)
Running_headcount  <- sum(dataSetAgg$Active)/nrow(dataSetAgg)
Annual_turnover <- (Running_terminations/Running_headcount)*12
```

Below is a description of what I mean by Running_termination, Running_headcount, and Annual_turnover.

```
#Running_terminations <-
```

should be (Terminations in month 1) + (Terminations in month 2)... / # of months

```
#Running_headcount <-
```

should be (Headcount in month 1) + (Headcount in month 2)... / # of months

```
#Annual_turnover <-
```

(Running terminations / Running headcount) * 12

**What I would like to do is calculate the Annual_turnover via specified variables**

**For example,**

```
Male_turnover <-
Male_and_fulltime_turnover <-
Male_and_female_and_TypeA_and_parttime_turnover <-
```

etc....

Is there a relatively simple way to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: there was not 29 days in february 2015

Comment: Your code does not reproduce your data (4 active in january, not 3)

Comment: Thank you, both are typos as I wrote it out manually.

Comment: Try to run your code in new environment (to avoid existing variables) and new R session (to avoid already loaded library) before posting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum(condition)` to count the lines where condition=TRUE:

- Number of lines with Status='Termination':

  ```
  sum(dataSet$Status=='Termination')
  3
  ```
- Number of lines with Status='Termination' and Gender='Male':

  ```
  sum(dataSet$Status=='Termination' & dataSet$Gender=='Male')
  1
  ```

You can also use `length()` to count the number of items:

- Number of (unique) month

  ```
  length(unique(dataSet$As.Of.Month))
  3
  ```

Comment: I edited my question to include what I meant by Running_termination, Running_headcount, and Annual_turnover. I tried your advice but I seem to be getting NaN's

Comment: Okay, so your code works for Annual_turnover works perfectly and gives me the accurate overall running turnover, but the code for Male_turnover and Male_and_fulltime_turnover gives me the exact same valuesr. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your new edit works! Many thanks to you my good sir!